# Как убрать с экрана клавиатуру при клике >не< на EditText? (устранить двойное открытие клавиатуры)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

При выполнении данной функции при клике на EditText происходит закрытие и повторное открытие клавиатуры. А нужно чтобы данная функция запускалась только если клик был не по EditText. Если по EditText - то не нужно закрывать клавиатуру.
То есть нужно: если входим в EditText - то функция не срабатывает. И наоборот если кликнули на любое место, кроме EditText - то код пусть работает.
EditText расположены во фрагменте, функция находится в activity.

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        val v: View? = currentFocus
        (v as? EditText)?.let {
            it.clearFocus()
            val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(it.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
}
```

Comment: Код у вас есть, перепишите условия его срабатывания и готово. Сейчас у вас идет приведение к EditText и если оно удачное, то снимается фокус и клавиатура скрывается. Пишите код и спрашивайте.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, запутался, ведь вроде так и надо , чтобы если выходишь из EditText клавиатура скрывалась, только надо ещё отслеживать вторым условием куда приходит клик - то есть если кликаешь в другой EditText - то не надо запускать функцию...

Comment: Как по мне, в вашем коде намешаны два понятия разного порядка. Touch event событие более низкого уровня, чем UI focus. Не проще повесить на нужные контролы один общий `View.OnFocusChangeListener` и там все делать? Пример кода:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61606601/5479247

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, этот код тоже брал отсюда... И его как бы "хвалили"... В приведенном вами примере в этом месте`else{
              // Do something when Focus is not on the EditText
            }` я могу просто скрывать клавиатуру?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja ___Но на самом деле этот вопрос вырос из ситуации, что при печатании текста в EditText, если понадобиться открыть drawer по кнопке "гамбургер", то "гамбургер" не реагирует на закрытие клавиатуры и открывается при открытой клавиатуре и корежится....(по команде`binding.root.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->`). Хотя эта команда работает так как мне нужно - клавиатура закрывается на любом месте кроме EditText. А код в моем вопросе перебивает "гамбургер", клавиатура закрывается перед тем как откроется drawer, но зато появилось ненужное лишнее закрытие/открытие